# Reverse characters of each element in a cell array (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, reverse, cell-array

I have a cell array as follows:

```
    celldata = {'AB'; 'BE'; 'BC'}
```

How can I create a cell array which characters of each element in a cell array 'celldata' are reversed. The output should be as follows:

```
    recelldata = {'BA'; 'EB'; 'CB'}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use fliplr, but it operates on each index of the cell instead of the whole cell. To wrap it all in one line, use cellfun

```
recelldata = cellfun(@(x) fliplr(x), celldata,'UniformOutput', false)

>>'BA'
  'EB'
  'CB'
```

Comment: FYI, you can also use the function handle instead of creating an anonymous function: `cellfun(@fliplr, celldata, 'UniformOutput', false)`